# How to modify and use a function of an R package?

Tags: r, function

My question is regarding [How do you adjust/control the scale in a treemap (using the 'portfolio' library) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561423/how-do-you-adjust-control-the-scale-in-a-treemap-using-the-portfolio-library).

I modified `seq(-1,0` to `seq(0,1` as recommended in one of the answers. I then copied and pasted the entire `map.market` function into R, but am unable to call the modified version that I just pasted. When I type `map.market`, the original definition of the function "portfolio" is printed within the R editor window. How can I run the version that I just pasted?

Comment: save it in a file and use `source("file_path.R")`.

Answer (score 6):

If you just copy and paste, the function is not really saved in your session. You need to assign it to an object in R. When you type the name of the function `map.market`, you get the code:

```
function(...)
{
# all
# the code 
# of the function
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000007dd9aa0>
<environment: namespace:portfolio>
```

So, you have to copy everything before `<bytecode>` and `<environment>` lines, modify and save it to an object

```
map.market2 = function(...)
{
# all
# the code 
# of the function (with modifications)
}
```

Now, you can use the new modified function `map.market2` as desired. You can name it `map.market` if you want, but check that doesn't break the rest of your code. For example, if you have used the original function before, because the new modified function will have precedence over the original one.